# Fix Texture Rendering?

Tags: texturing

I'm texturing a table with multiple textures. I've essentially placed one texture on the top of the table and another for the legs. The entire model is one piece and the model's materials are set to the two I am using. When I press render it only displays the texture that is top of the materials list and doesn't place it where I had it originally. How can I fix this?

Comment: Nevermind finally figured it out, I had to go into edit mode, select every face with on the legs and assign the legs material to it, then the same for the top of the table

Comment: I would suggest you consider deleting this question, if you no longer need help, because it already has an answer. Sometimes people will come to down-vote questions that have other answers, so you may want to avoid that. It's your choice though.